# Installed Intervention with Laravel but resize method does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I am using Intervention with Laravel 5.2, I have installed it using Composer and `included Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class` and `'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class in the config/app.php`

I have also added the use statement to the Controller where I am using it use `Intervention\Image\ImageManager;`

Here is my function where I am trying to process the photo, but when I submit the form that calls this function I get this error message

```
 BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
    Method resize does not exist.
```

Function

```
public function postAvatarUpload(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|image|max:3000|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
        ]);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $usersname = $user->username;
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $resizedImg = $file->resize(200,200);
        $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = $usersname . '.' . $ext;
        if (Storage::disk('public')->has($usersname)) {
            Storage::delete($usersname);
        }
           Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, File::get($resizedImg));
           $avatarPath = Storage::url($filename);
            Auth::user()->update([
                'image' => $avatarPath,
            ]);

        return redirect()->route('profile.index', 
                ['username' => Auth::user()->username]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should save the file and then create instance (object) of `ImageManager` using the method `make`.

Example:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('image');

    $path = 'path/to';
    $fileName = 'example_name.' . $file->extension();

    $file->move($path, $fileName);

    $image = ImageManager::make($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName);
}
```

Also, you may use the facade `Intervention\Image\Facades\Image` instead of `ImageManager` class.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the resize method on the file, not Intervention.
Should work if you replace `$resizedImg = $file->resize(200,200);` with `$resizedImg = Image::make($file)->resize(200,200);` I think.